# Animate text in an emacs buffer

Tags: animate

For educational purposes I wish to replay the characters that I enter in the buffer at some slow typing speed. Selecting the regions I could do this in would also be great.

Is there any emacs package that provides such a feature?

Comment: you can find some answers on this page http://dantorop.info/project/emacs-animation/

Answer (score 1):

This will get you part way there:

```lisp
(defun pause () (sleep-for 0.7))

(define-minor-mode slowdown-mode "..." nil nil nil
  (if slowdown-mode
      (add-hook 'post-command-hook #'pause)
    (remove-hook 'post-command-hook #'pause)))
```

This doesn't "replay", and you can't apply it to a region. But it does show you how to slow things down.

`M-x slowdown-mode` to turn it on/off.

Change the `0.7` to whatever pause length you like.